# complex tree/forest scenario-tree

Tags: diagrams, forest, trees

I have tried to play around with different tree-structures and looked through some threads here but i cant even get close to what i want:

[image]

The difficulties:

- how to draw the "generator" term.
- how to create the different roots (y^1, y^2, y^3).
- how to create the interval on the top mapping up the different stages (I_0^1, I_1^1, ..,)
- how to create the dots from Y^2 to Y^k, should "tell" the reader that there are multiple such roots.
- put the text on the edges.

is anyone able to help me on these matters?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is always good to show what you tried already. This will give others a better idea of what you want to achieve and which tools you would like to use.

Comment: Welcome. // Things you should learn from the pgfmanual (tikz.dev), ordered by your list of questions: 1) \node, 2) \node, node names or \coordinate, 3) \draw, 4) \node and \foreach, 5) \node or the various choices for label. // Things will be easier for everybody once you post your code, which compiles when copied.

Answer (score 1):

Here we go, the code should be quite self-contained. Enjoy the beauty of Ti*k*Z!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    , font = \sffamily % I love sans serif in figures
    , thick % this is also my preference
    % define some styles that can be reused
    , n f/.style = { % node fill
      , draw
      , fill = black
      , circle
      , inner sep = 0
      , outer sep = 0
      , minimum width = 1mm
    }
    , n o/.style = { % node outline
      , draw
      , circle
      , inner sep = 0
      , outer sep = 0
      , minimum width = 1mm
    }
    , n v/.style = { % node vertical
      , draw
      , fill
      , inner sep = 0
      , outer sep = .3mm
      , minimum width = .4mm
      , minimum height = 3mm
    }
  ]
    \node (generator) {Generator};
    \foreach \x in {-45, -15, 15, 45} {
      \draw [->, shorten < = 2mm] ([xshift = -2mm]generator.east) -- ++(\x:10mm);
    }
    \foreach [count = \i] \y in {30, 0, -40} { % y is the position of y
      \def\k{\ifnum\i=3k\else\i\fi} % the superscript
      \node (y-\i) [right = 20mm of generator, yshift = \y mm, minimum width = 5mm] {$y^\k$};
      \node (y-\i-n) at (y-\i.east) [n f] {};
      \foreach [count = \j] \yc in {10, 0, -10} {
        \draw (y-\i-n.center) -- ++ (20mm, \yc mm) node (C-\i-\j) [n f] {}
                                                   node [midway, above, font = \scriptsize] {$B_\j^1$}
                                                   node (C-\i-\j) [above] {$C_\j^\k$}
                              -- ++ (30mm, 0)      node (e-\i-\j) [right, n o] {}
                                                   node [midway, above, font = \small] {$\ifnum\i=1C_\j^\k+k+Z\else\dots\fi$};
      }
    }
    \draw [dashed] (y-2-n) -- (y-3-n);
    \node (a-1) [n v] at ([yshift = 20mm]C-1-1.center) {};
    \draw [shorten > = -.5mm] (a-1.center) -- ++ (+30mm, 0) node [midway, above, font = \small] {$I_1^1,I_1^2$}
                                                            node [right, n v] {};
    \draw [shorten > = -.5mm] (a-1.center) -- ++ (-20mm, 0) node [midway, above, font = \small] {$I_0^1$}
                                                            node [left , n v] {};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I particularly love `\foreach` with `\ifnum` and `\if`.

[image: Result]